# JMS outbound channel adapter java-based configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jms, spring-integration

Is there any way to configure JMS outbound channel adapter

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" destination="outQueue" channel="exampleChannel"/>
```

by the similar "easy" way, but using only java-based (annotations) configuration?
If no, so what is the simplest way to achieve this point?

Answer (score 2):

Eugene, I've already pointed you out to the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl). It is exactly the best way to simplify Spring Integration from Java-based config.

Since it isn't the first your similar question, please, pay attention to that project, which has a simple fusion with Core SI:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("exampleChannel")
                .handleWithAdapter(h ->
                    h.jms(this.jmsConnectionFactory).destination("outQueue"))
                .get();
}
```

Otherwise it may look like this for the raw Java & Annotation configuration:

```
@Bean
@serviceActivator(inputChannel = "exampleChannel")
public MessageHandler jsmOutboundAdapter() {
   JmsTemplate template = new DynamicJmsTemplate();
   template.setConnectionFactory(this.jmsConnectionFactory);
   JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(template);
   handler.setDestinationName("outQueue");
   return handler;
}
```

Comment: actually Java 8 in the examples, it is the reason why I didn't take into account DSL :)